# Bad Request Status Error Code (400): YouTube API - (Python)

Tags: python, google-api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am doing a project that calls the YouTube API to import songs from my Liked Videos to a Spotify Playlist.

I am having this issue when running a program with YouTube Data API v3 in the MacOS Terminal. It shows this error code.

```
exceptions.ResponseException: Response gave status code 400
```

**My endpoint is:**
[https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/{user_id}/playlists](https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/%7Buser_id%7D/playlists)

**HTTP Method:** POST

Here is my executable code:

```py
import json
import os

import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
import googleapiclient.discovery
import googleapiclient.errors
import requests
import youtube_dl

from exceptions import ResponseException
from secrets import spotify_token, spotify_user_id


class CreatePlaylist:
    def __init__(self):
        self.youtube_client = self.get_youtube_client()
        self.all_song_info = {}

    def get_youtube_client(self):
        """ Log Into Youtube, Copied from Youtube Data API """
        # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally.
        # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled in production.
        os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

        api_service_name = "youtube"
        api_version = "v3"
        client_secrets_file = "client_secret.json"

        # Get credentials and create an API client
        scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"]
        flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            client_secrets_file, scopes)
        credentials = flow.run_console()

        # from the Youtube DATA API
        youtube_client = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
            api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)

        return youtube_client

    def get_liked_videos(self):
        """Grab Our Liked Videos & Create A Dictionary Of Important Song Information"""
        request = self.youtube_client.videos().list(
            part="snippet,contentDetails,statistics",
            myRating="like"
        )
        response = request.execute()

        # collect each video and get important information
        for item in response["items"]:
            video_title = item["snippet"]["title"]
            youtube_url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={}".format(
                item["id"])

            # use youtube_dl to collect the song name & artist name
            video = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL({}).extract_info(
                youtube_url, download=False)
            song_name = video["track"]
            artist = video["artist"]

            if song_name is not None and artist is not None:
                # save all important info and skip any missing song and artist
                self.all_song_info[video_title] = {
                    "youtube_url": youtube_url,
                    "song_name": song_name,
                    "artist": artist,

                    # add the uri, easy to get song to put into playlist
                    "spotify_uri": self.get_spotify_uri(song_name, artist)

                }

    def create_playlist(self):
        """Create A New Playlist"""
        request_body = json.dumps({
            "name": "Youtube Liked Vids",
            "description": "All Liked Youtube Videos",
            "public": True
        })

        query = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/{}/playlists".format(
            spotify_user_id)
        response = requests.post(
            query,
            data=request_body,
            headers={
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(spotify_token)
            }
        )
        response_json = response.json()

        # playlist id
        return response_json["id"]

    def get_spotify_uri(self, song_name, artist):
        """Search For the Song"""
        query = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=track%3A{}+artist%3A{}&type=track&offset=0&limit=20".format(
            song_name,
            artist
        )
        response = requests.get(
            query,
            headers={
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(spotify_token)
            }
        )
        response_json = response.json()
        songs = response_json["tracks"]["items"]

        # only use the first song
        uri = songs[0]["uri"]

        return uri

    def add_song_to_playlist(self):
        """Add all liked songs into a new Spotify playlist"""
        # populate dictionary with our liked songs
        self.get_liked_videos()

        # collect all of uri
        uris = [info["spotify_uri"]
                for song, info in self.all_song_info.items()]

        # create a new playlist
        playlist_id = self.create_playlist()

        # add all songs into new playlist
        request_data = json.dumps(uris)

        query = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/{}/tracks".format(
            playlist_id)

        response = requests.post(
            query,
            data=request_data,
            headers={
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(spotify_token)
            }
        )

        # check for valid response status
        if response.status_code != 200:
            raise ResponseException(response.status_code)

        response_json = response.json()
        return response_json


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cp = CreatePlaylist()
    cp.add_song_to_playlist()
```

When ran in terminal:

```py
192:SpotifyGeneratePlaylist-master paulkasidit$ python3 create_playlist.py
Please visit this URL to authorize this application: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=550010103020-vdhbp618n05m8bf1sheerj0hsq0he3c4.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyoutube.readonly&state=M1EQTEk5OW8RZxFmQknGvDZzdPgVlc&prompt=consent&access_type=offline
Enter the authorization code: 4/3gGLoigOQk85ZIFwEb-vhhVQ1czAaJmNZUSTRLoL-s5gEv0FNb-Q3Kk
[youtube] RiEXuE1uN0E: Downloading webpage
[youtube] wQuo7DhJ5dg: Downloading webpage
[youtube] wQuo7DhJ5dg: Downloading MPD manifest
[youtube] I7tehcZja_4: Downloading webpage
[youtube] 2MpZO7_u-oM: Downloading webpage
[youtube] aYjHOf6-SmM: Downloading webpage
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "create_playlist.py", line 154, in <module>
    cp.add_song_to_playlist()
  File "create_playlist.py", line 146, in add_song_to_playlist
    raise ResponseException(response.status_code)
**exceptions.ResponseException: Response gave status code 400**
```

Source Project Link: https://github.com/TheComeUpCode/SpotifyGeneratePlaylist

- Has anybody else encountered this issue when working with the Google
  API
  or YouTube API? Is there a solution to this?
- I have 3000+ videos in my YouTube Liked Videos, could this be a
  factor for the error? (I've tried with an alternate account with only
  3 liked videos, and this error still occurs though.)

Thank You

*Sorry for reposting this question. I'm a complete beginner and I am not really good at asking good questions. I hope the details provided were sufficient.

Comment: Is `Response gave status code 400` comes from spotify APi, right?, have you discarded options like: if the playlist does not exists, or the song is not found on spotify and you're assuming the song is found? - I don't know about spotify APi, but, it might help if you provide examples of the videos/playlist from youtube you're adding to your spotify playlist.